# Boto3 Finding unused Security Groups

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand more on Boto3 scripting.

I want to search for unused security groups within several VPC's which are all in the same region

I am trying to get the python script here to work:
[boto3 searching unused security groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146114/boto3-searching-unused-security-groups)

So my `list-unused-sq.py` is shown below

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

sgs = list(ec2.security_groups.all())
insts = list(ec2.instances.all())

all_sgs = set([sg.group_name for sg in sgs])
all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupName'] for inst in insts for sg in inst.security_groups])
unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs

print 'Total SGs:', len(all_sgs)
print 'SGS attached to instances:', len(all_inst_sgs)
print 'Orphaned SGs:', len(unused_sgs)
print 'Unattached SG names:', unused_sgs
```

When i run the script i get the following error

```
./list-unused-sq.py: line 1: import: command not found
./list-unused-sq.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./list-unused-sq.py: line 3: `ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2') #You have to change this line based on how you pass AWS credentials and AWS config'
```

Is someone able to point out where i have gone wrong and what i need to do to correct it?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your first error line:

```
./list-unused-sq.py: line 1: import: command not found
```

Seems like your problem is not related with boto3 but in your script not recognizing your local python. [More info about your problem and how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275350/xx-py-line-1-import-command-not-found)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I really appreciate you replying and that was exactly what solved my issue!
.
.
`Total SGs: 78
SGS attached to instances: 30
Orphaned SGs: 48
Unattached SG names: set(['launch-wiz`